# What is the context for this panel of Superman tossing a cross at super-speed?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

I accidentally stumbled on this while browsing trivia about Superman.

[image: Superman is seemingly tossing away something that looks like a cross. There seems to be fume coming out of it, whether it means it's burning or it's poisonous gas or anything. Superman is saying: "... I'll get rid of this. A super-speed toss into the atmosphere--".]

Some people seemed to suggest this would be silver age Superman, but so far I was not able to find any context for it yet.

Which issue is this from and why is Superman tossing a fuming cross shaped object?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/superman/comments/o39k4b/why_is_superman_throwing_a_cross_which_comic_is/ discusses this a bit, and tracked down one possible source, but there's no issue cited. Someone else thinks it's a photoshop. Given it looks like it's burning, it could be one of his anti-KKK issue.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yeah, I came across that same Reddit, and someone seemed to mention in the comments that Superman never fought against Klan. Don't know how true it is though, since I don't know much about the comics materials.

Comment: They didn't adapt the famous radio show episode until 2009, which wouldn't fit this vintage look. So yeah... no dice there.

Comment: thats the weeknd in his new music video

Comment: I'm quite curious as to what was warrant a down vote. I genuinely tried to find where it was coming from and failed to find it. If I could have a feedback on what should be improved, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a reference on Tumblr to this meme, with someone saying it's from [World's Finest Volume 1 #286](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_286) where Superman does fight the Klan.

> When Clark Kent returns to his apartment, he notices that his neighbor's dog is missing and using his x-ray vision, he finds the puppy at the mercy of a satanic cult and about to be sacrificed. Superman stops the senseless murder and attacks the maniacs. However, he is once again attacked by the dark cloud and is temporarily incapacitated. Moments later in Gotham City, Lucius Fox returns home only to find a large faction of the Ku Klux Klan waiting for him outside his house.

[image: The page from the issue from which the aforementioned panel was taken from. We can see that it's no mere cross, but a red hot burning one.]

Comment: I can confirm this. I'm glad this didn't take nearly as long as Marvel's vibrating horse to find.

Comment: @Clockwork: Thank you. The best I'd found so far was possibly signing up for a free trial with DC Universe to be able to grab an image.